# PHP5 Laravel - Replace all object attributes that are equal to a value

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

I'm building a website with Laravel 5 framework and I'm into a little trouble.

I extracted an array of objects from database with Eloquent model  and I passed it to a view.

The format of array is like that:

```
array[object1{prop1:xxxx, prop2: xxxx}, object2{prop1:xxxx,prop2:xxxx}...]
```

The problem is that some proprieties values are `false` so when i print with `{{ object1->propriety }}` it doesn't print anything.

I want to replace all false proprieties in all objects in the array without placing the statement `if (!obj1->prop) do something` all times, because objects are many.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use shorthand if statements: http://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ternary operators in your views:

```
{{ $object->boolean_attribute ? 'true' : 'false' }}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a fast way to replace a value before printing, but I need to replace all false proprieties in one step (with a cycle for example)

Comment: Why do you want to replace the values after retrieval? Why not either store as something other than a boolean, or output a modified value?

Comment: That's true, but the value in the DB is "universal", it isn't used only for printing something on the page, so it cannot be changed directly on the table.

Comment: Well quite, which is why replacing all the values on the model, while possible, would be a bad practice. It would invalidate the model in all other use cases apart from view output. What is the problem with just using a ternary operator in the view?

Comment: Maybe it would be faster and less code lines. However for now I'm using ternary operators. Thank you

Comment: No problem. I doubt there would be a faster way, but if you don't like the bloat in the view, then you could always move the ternary statement into a getter on the model.